# How to convert strong parameter rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My form sends data like

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"",
 "org_document"=>{"is_fin_changed"=>"Y"},
 "commit"=>"Save",
 "document_type"=>"FIN_CART"}
```

So, I wrote strong parameter like

```
 def req_document_params
    params.fetch(:org_document,{}).permit(:document_type,:is_fin_changed)
 end
```

But it only sends `{"is_fin_changed"=>"Y"}` Not sure what is wrong!
Any help appreciated:)

Comment: Don't you see the `document_type` is out of `org_document` params? Show the code related to that request.

Comment: I gave the code related to the request. Not sure how do I include the `:document_type`

Comment: Why people put -1 vote for constructive question. Don't you see that author has only one point of reputation? Instead of put answer you vote down :/

Comment: @learner2017 Show the full form code please.

Comment: hey @learner2017, you will need to modify your form view so it could include `document_type` inside `org_document`. It is fairly easy with rails form builder.  Can you share your view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case `fetch` method return value of `:org_document` so it returns 
`{"is_fin_changed"=>"Y"}` then you call `permit` , but in `{"is_fin_changed"=>"Y"}` there isn't `:document_type`

Try

```
 def req_document_params
   params.require(:org_document).permit(:is_fin_changed).merge(params.permit(:document_type))
 end
```